# How to disable local geographic names on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, localization

For some reason Google Maps displays local geographic names for each country, even when the country uses non-Latin script, which makes it completely unreadable.

Is there a way to force it to show English names for all locations worldwide?

Comment: @pnuts Has there been any development on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to go to
https://www.google.com/preferences

There, you may set up your region settings (to US for example).

I tried, and then went to maps.google.com; tried several countries (such as Saudi Arabia) and they showed a readable name for each city. However names are in Arabic). I tried the same with Russia (Cyrillic) and China (Chinese letters), it worked with name in Latin characters; but always adding the local name.